# Как использовать методы которые требуют активити без активити?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

У меня есть девайс с BLE и UART сервис к нему

Такие методы, как:

```
(BluetoothManager) this.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
```

и

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { ...
```

и

```
Intent bindIntent = new Intent(this, UartService.class);
```

и т.п. требуют активити в виде this

Но мне нужно сделать глобальный класс на все это дело, иначе придется переподключатся к BLE девайсу, что не есть хорошо

Что делать в этом случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы использовать методы активности там где ее нет, в вашем случае это отдельный от активности класс, вам нужно передать `context` в метод этого класса и дальше уже можно будет использовать методы активности. Лучше всего передавать `ApplicationContext`. Но вы должны предотвратить утечки памяти при работе с приложение так как это может повлиять на дальнейшую работу программы. Либо вы можете передать в конструктор класса `context`:

```
public class Example {
    protected Context context;

    public Example(Context context){
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

и там уже брать `ApplicationContext` чтобы избежать утечек памяти. [Тут](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) написано про утечки более подробно.

Comment: метод runOnUiTread() это метод активити, а не контекста и передача контекста куда бы то ни было не поможет его выполнить

Comment: @pavlofff, и правда) чет я протупил немного, получается что без активности его все-равно не выполнишь

Comment: более того, нет никакого смысла выполнять его вне активити

Comment: Но как я понял для методов, к примеру requestPermissions, нужен AppCompatActivity, а не Context

Comment: ох, ваш метод возвращает null при выполнении getApplicationContext